# Reference an previously made object

Tags: c#, object

In my model class I have a Professor and a Department like this:

```
public class Professor
{
    public int ProfessorID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public bool Tenured { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Professor> Professors { get; set; }
}
```

and I am trying to make a seed method where I can populate the department when I create a new professor from a previously created department.  How do I reference the previously created department in the SeedProfessor function?

```
    private static List<Department> SeedDepartments()
    {
        var departments = new List<Department> 
        { 
            new Department{
                DepartmentID = 1,
                Name = "Psychology"
            }
        };
        return departments;
    }

    private static List<Professor> SeedProfessors()
    {
        var professors = new List<Professor> 
        { 
            new Professor{
                ProfessorID = 1,
                Name = "John Doe",
                Department = (***HERE IS WHERE I DON'T UNDERSTAND***)
                Tenured = true
            }
        };
        return professors;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Usually you use a Dictionary rather than a List.  Dictionaries allow you to retrieve existing items by their key.  Either way, pass the collection of departments to `SeedProfessors`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what is the issue here. But you could refer the Department using a simple LINQ

```
var professors = new List<Professor> 
        { 
            new Professor{
                ProfessorID = 1,
                Name = "John Doe",
                Department = SeedDepartments().FirstOrDefault(),
                Tenured = true
            }
        };
```

OR

```
new Professor
          {
            ProfessorID = 1,
            Name = "John Doe",
            Department = SeedDepartments().Where(x => x.Name = "Psychology").FirstOrDefault(),
            Tenured = true
          }
```

Comment: I have updated the code to include .FirstOrDefault() in the second scenario as well. You could mark it as answer for the sake of others if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you for answering.  I don't have a high enough reputation number on stack exchange to upvote yet.  The line:

> Department = SeedDepartments().FirstOrDefault(),

worked perfect, but I also wanted to try and add a specific department.  If I did:

> Department = SeedDepartments().Where(d => d.DepartmentID == 1),

I would get an error that said:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'SRS.Models.Department'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)  D:\Projects\SRS\SRS\Models\DbInitializer.cs 75  26  SRS

So, I wrote this:

> Department = SeedDepartments().Where(x=>x.Name ==
>   "Psychology").FirstOrDefault(),

and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

a very quick fix for that:

```
private static List<Department> departments;
private static List<Professor> professors;

private static List<Department> SeedDepartments()
{
    if (departments == null)
    {
      departments = new List<Department> 
      { 
          new Department
          {
            DepartmentID = 1,
            Name = "Psychology"
          }
      };
    }

    return departments;
}

private static List<Professor> SeedProfessors()
{
    if (professors == null)
    {
       professors = new List<Professor> 
       { 
          new Professor
          {
            ProfessorID = 1,
            Name = "John Doe",
            Department = SeedDepartments().Where(d => d.DepartmentID == 1), //SeedDepartments()[0],
            Tenured = true
          }
       };
    }

    return professors;
}
```

assuming that the departments load before the proffesors.

but i really think that you really should take **static c'tor** as an alternative as described in msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx